# getting 'Invariant Violation: `refreshing` prop must be set as a boolean in order to use `onRefresh`, but got `undefined`'

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When the home screen loads I get 'Invariant Violation: `refreshing` prop must be set as a boolean in order to use `onRefresh`, but got `undefined`'  please help.

```
class Home extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      suggestionList:[],
      refreshing:false,
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    this.setState({

      suggestionList: nextProps.result.suggestionsArray ,
      lastSuggestionKey : nextProps.result.lastSuggestionKey,
      refreshing : false

    });

}

handleRowPress = (item) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('UserDetails', item);
};

handleMoreRequest = () => {
  this.props.getOld(this.state.lastSuggestionKey);
};

handleRefresh = () => {

  this.setState({
    lastSuggestionKey: '',
    refreshing: true
  });

  this.props.getAll();
};

componentWillMount() {

  this.props.getAll();

}

 render() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>

      <FlatList
        style={{backgroundColor: colors.background}}
        data={this.state.suggestionList}
        renderItem={(item) => 
          <CardItem contact={item.item} 
                    onPress={() => this.handleRowPress(item)}
                    onCommentPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SuggestionList')}/>
        }
        keyExtractor={item => item.suggestionid}
        refeshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
        onEndReached={this.handleMoreRequest}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
      />

    </View>
  );

  }
   }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle:{
    flex:1, 
    backgroundColor: colors.background
  },
});

function mapStateToProps({ suggestion }) {
  return { 
    result: suggestion.result,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

Comment: In addition to your original question, I think you forgot to bind your functions `handleRefresh` &co. to the current context in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo on your FlatList props, it should be `refreshing` instead of `refeshing`.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same thing, I found this problem is because the use of `onRefresh` props must coincide with the use of `refreshing={condition}` props.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Apparently, by setting the **refreshing** props right before the **onRefresh** prop and it worked. Give it a try.

```
`refreshing={refreshing}
    onRefresh={() => {
      setItem(sumItemsArray);
    }}
  />
```